# Filtering JSON array as easy as XML

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, xml

In my project I am moving from XML format to JSON format.
I have XML which consists from nodes like this:

```
<Creature>
    <Name>Someone</Name>
    <Desert>false</Desert>
    <Woods>false</Woods>
    <Mountains>false</Mountains>
    <Swamp>false</Swamp>
</Creature>
```

And the radio list with values equal to the tags names. Like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="creature_terrain" value="Desert" />Desert<br>
```

Old code filtered XML list by doing this:

```
let selector = 'Creature > ' + selectedTerrain + ':contains("true")';
var filteredCreatures = $(creaturesArray).find(selector).parent();
```

And so now I have JSON array:

```
  {
    "Name": "Someone",
    "Desert": false,
    "Woods": false,
    "Mountains": false,
    "Swamp": false
  }
```

But I can't find a way to filter it as elegant as it was with XML. The only way I see is to switch/case. Any suggestions?

Comment: That isn't a JSON array, an array would have brackets [ ]. Or would you have more than one of those with different data?

Answer (score 2):

If it actually is an array, you can use `filter` to go through looking for the matching terrain is true.

**EDIT**: You could leave out the == true as it will evaluate it as boolean, but I prefer having it as its easier to read and understand.

```js
const creatures = [
  {
    "Name": "None",
    "Desert": false,
    "Woods": false,
    "Mountains": false,
    "Swamp": false
  },
  {
    "Name": "Swamp",
    "Desert": false,
    "Woods": false,
    "Mountains": false,
    "Swamp": true
  }
]

const terrain = "Swamp";

const creature = creatures.filter((e) => e[terrain] == true)

console.log(creature)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an *array* of objects rather than just one object you can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter out those object that match a specific condition.

Let's expand your example.

1. There are two objects (I've lowercased the key names). One matches "desert" the other "swamp". There are corresponding radio inputs for demonstration.
2. I've attached an event listener to the `fieldset` element to catch events from its children ([event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/)).
3. When a change event is fired the handler checks first to see if the element that fired the event was an radio button. Then it `filters` out the objects into a new array that match the "is the value of this object key true?" condition. We use the `value` of the changed radio button as the object key that we want to inspect.
4. For convenience this filtered array of objects is displayed in an output element.

```js
const data=[{name:"Someone",desert:false,woods:false,mountains:false,swamp:true},{name:"Someone 2",desert:true,woods:false,mountains:false,swamp:false}];

// Get the terrain and output elements
const terrain = document.querySelector('.terrain');
const output = document.querySelector('.output');

// Add a listener to the terrain (fieldset) element
terrain.addEventListener('change', handleInput);

// When the terrain element catches an event
function handleInput(e) {

  // It checks to see if its a corresponding
  // creature_terrain radio button
  if (e.target.matches('[name="creature_terrain"]')) {
    
    // Assigns the changed radio input's value to `key`
    const key = e.target.value;

    // And uses that key in the condition to filter
    // those objects where there is a match
    const filtered = data.filter(obj => obj[key]);

    // If there are objects in the filtered array
    // show them in the output element
    if (filtered.length) {
      output.textContent = JSON.stringify(filtered, null, 2);
    } else {
      output.textContent = '';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
code { display: block; margin-top: 1rem; }
```

```html
<fieldset class="terrain">
  <legend>Terrain</legend>
  <input type="radio" name="creature_terrain" value="desert" />Desert
  <input type="radio" name="creature_terrain" value="swamp" />Swamp
</fieldset>
<pre><code class="output"></code></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try javascript native array methods like [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) or [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```
const filteredCreatures = creaturesArray.filter(creature => creature.Desert);
```